# handling timeout in a long running loop

Tags: c#

I have a method which should execute within given time or it should throw 'Timeout' exception. Basically it has a long running loop. Calculating timeout in every pass of loop seems expensive:

```
private void DoSomethingGood(int timeoutSeconds)
{
    var startTime=DateTime.Now;
    int count=100000000; //some big number

    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        //code to to take care of timeout.
        var ellapsedSeconds =(DateTime.Now-startTime).TotalSeconds;
        if(ellapsedSeconds>=timeoutSeconds)
        {
            throw new TimeoutException("Timeout");
        }

        /*some more code here*/

    }
}
```

(calling above method without other code, itself is taking more than 2 seconds, largely due to DateTime.Now statement)

Can someone suggest a better way of doing it?

I am fine with +-few-milliseconds.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.net construct for while loop with timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629219/net-construct-for-while-loop-with-timeout)

Comment: Why not use build-in `System.Timers.Timer`?

Comment: Your DateTime.Now is NOT taking 2 seconds. If it does, you should check your computer.

Comment: @peer if you run above code without "DateTime.Now" it finishes very fast. With this statement it takes considerable amount of time.

Comment: Note: you might want to use `UtcNow` instead of `Now` (in both cases) - otherwise it could fail when the timezone / daylight-savings-time changes.

Comment: @MarcGravell it wont fail, as I am not taking DateTime from outside.

Comment: DateTime.UtcNow will give you better performance than datetime.now because it will not need to convert the time to your local timezone. This might solve your performance hit.

Comment: @Falaque er, yes it will fail. If the loop starts just before daylight-savings time, you might either (depending on the direction of the change) either not detect the timeout at all for an hour (etc), or might detect it incorrectly too early.

Comment: @MarcGravell, oops, I dont know this DayLight saving problem, so you mean, DateTime.UtcNow wont fail?

Comment: @Falaque correct; as long as nobody changes the actual system clock itself (which is unrelated to things like timezone and DST settings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only do that check periodically? for example:

```
if((i % 100) == 0) { /* check for timeout */ }
```

Or adjust to `1000`, `10000` etc depending on how fast it needs to notice the timeout.

Comment: Note: you can also improve the test performance by pre-calculating the timeout via `var timeout = startTime.AddSeconds(timeoutSeconds);` and just checking `if(DateTime.[Utc]Now>=timeout)` - but it probably isn't worth it.

Comment: thing is checking timeout itself is taking lot of time.

Comment: @Falaque hence you check it less often, as per the above.